# Treating values like ("<10", "100- 400", "100+") in a data set in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I want to predict the values in a data set in R, but the values are in format like 
 <10 and  100-400 and 100+.  Also under which category does they fall,Categorical or continuous variables?

Comment: You might consider an ordered variable.  Since you are asking about R,   take a look at the help page `factor` and look at the `ordered` argument`.

Comment: This is really a statistical question.  Data like that is called censored data.

Comment: Thank you...@G5W

Comment: Thankyou...@user2554330.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example if you creating a `factor` from scratch:

```
vals <- c("100-400", "<100", "400+")

vector <- sample(vals, 20, replace = TRUE)
vector

ordered <- factor(vector, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("<100", "100-400", "400+"))
ordered
```

The order depends on the order of the vector's values in `levels` argument.

If you already have a `factor` variable you want to use `ordered()` function:

```
factor1 <- factor(sample(vals, 20, replace=TRUE),
                  levels = c("400+", "<100", "100-400"))
factor1

factor1 <- ordered(factor1, levels = c("<100", "100-400", "400+"))
factor1
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: i have a data set with 14 variables, two columns named "experience" and "company_size" have different values in them, but the values are in format like "100 - 500" or "<10", ">500", "300+",and i want to predict the missing values in it. So, how should i deal with these values to make a predictive model. @balkon16

Comment: @Priyanshusangal, the problem you are referring to is called **imputation** of missing values (NAs). Depending on the number of missing observations you can either drop missing values (if there is only few of them) or try to predict them. Considering the latter: you can either make predictions based on the column itself or use other columns as well. If you are using only the column itself the simplest way is to put the most frequent value in the place of NAs. Other solution would be to assume that values in the column come from some kind of distribution and every value has its probability.

Comment: Thankyou...@balkon16